# IDE/Editores de texto para Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, debug, ide, editor-de-texto

Quais as melhores opções de IDE ou Editores de texto para desenvolvimento em NodeJS? Minha necessidade é desenvolvimento de grandes projetos com  ***JavaScript / Node.js***, segue abaixo alguma das opções que encontrei. Se possível citar as vantagens de utilizar software indicado.

- Nodeclipse
- Aptana Studio
- Sublime Text 2
- Vim

Comment: IDE ou editores? IDE eu conheço o Netbeans, tem plugin para Node.

Comment: Estou procurando IDE mesmo.. vou dar um olhada no Netbeans aqui .. valeu

Comment: Esta pergunta não agrega valor, por ser baseada em opiniões e não em fatos. Sabemos que cada pessoa tem preferência, um recurso próprio da ferramenta.

Comment: [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) com [Node.js Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx), assim como à tool para o Grunt [TRX - Task Runner Explorer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708) e [Grunt Launcher](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcbc5325-79ef-4b72-960e-0a51ee33a0ff) e um intellisense para o NPM [NPM/NBower Package Intellisense](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/65748cdb-4087-497e-a394-2e3449c8e61e)

Comment: VS Community 2015 está uma delícia para Node.js

Comment: Optei pelo VS mesmo, funciona lindamente!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Minha sugestão como uma boa IDE é o [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), que apesar de ser paga, a licensa individual cabe no bolso.

Mas como uma opção gratuita eu concordo com o @re22 e recomendo o [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) com o [plugin de Node](http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/installing-nodejs-on-netbeans/).